# How do I generate Python Selenium code from a GUI?

Tags: selenium

Is there a GUI that will generate Selenium code for me? E.g. I want to click on element and type and then click the submit button and have Selenium code auto generated for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Selenium IDE](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/). Here is how to export working code, note that python is an option:

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/code-export